# Upload image using ionic, angular, and django+restframework

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

I'm developping an app, in which I want to be able to upload a photo to the backend (restframework + django).

For the backend side, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.machinalis.com/blog/image-fields-with-django-rest-framework/).
When I use :

```
curl --verbose --header "Authorization: token {TOKEN}" --header "Accept: application/json; indent=4" --request POST --form photo=@/home/.../uyuni.jpg {DOMAIN}/api/users/1/photo/
```

This works perfectly, the file is really created, and I can retrieve it afterwards, using ng-src.

Then, I want to wire frontend to upload photo.

Here I tried lots of ideas from forums or tutos like this [one](https://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs)

I have two different issues.

- If I copy the last tuto, I end up with a 400 Bad Request:
  Erreur d'analyse XML : aucun élément trouvé Emplacement : moz-nullprincipal:{1b4583fc...} Numéro de ligne 1, Colonne 1 :
  I don't know if it comes from backend or mozilla. I read about CORS issue, but this shouldn't be a problem, as I use ionic proxy.
- If I wire with cordova-plugin-camera, I have an URL (file:///home/.../example.jpg) returned, I don't know how to wire this to the FormData to use for the POST to the backend:

```
    var updateUserPhoto = function (userId, photoURI) {
    if (!photoURI) {return}
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('photo', photoURI);
    return $http.post(API_URL + "users/"+userId+"/photo/", fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {AUTHORIZATION: "Token "+window.localStorage['apiToken'], 'CONTENT-TYPE': undefined}
        });
    };
```

I tried to append an object in fd, like `{path: photoURI, name: 'blablabla'}`
In this issue, I end up with a Django error:

```
AttributeError at /api/users/1/photo/ 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I'm probably not that far, so I'd rather not use external snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I had very similar issues, and then some. This [Media plugin](http://market.ionic.io/plugins/onymos-media) from the Ionic marketplace resolved the issue by providing both base64 data as well as uri for me to use.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue. Ouf!

I used this on backend side:

```
import base64

from django.db.models import ImageField
from django.db.models.fields.files import ImageFieldFile
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile


def upload_to(instance, filename):
    return 'profiles/' + filename


def wrap(content):
    class File(InMemoryUploadedFile):
        def read(self):
            return base64.b64decode(super().read())
    return File(content.file, content.field_name, content.name, content.content_type, content.size, content.charset)


class Base64ImageFieldFile(ImageFieldFile):
    def save(self, name, content, save=True):
        super().save(name, wrap(content), save=True)


class Base64ImageField(ImageField):
    attr_class = Base64ImageFieldFile
```

And on frontend side:

To configure my resource:

```
var userActions = getActions(User);
var updatePhotoHeader = angular.copy(auth_header);
updatePhotoHeader['CONTENT-TYPE'] = undefined;

userActions['updatePhoto'] = {
    method: "POST",
    url: API_URL + "users/:userId/photo/",
    params: {userId: "@userId"},
    headers: updatePhotoHeader,
    transformRequest: function (data) {
        if (!data) {return}
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('photo', new Blob([data.photo], {type: 'image\/jpeg'}));
        return fd
    }
};
```

with this options for the camera (from cordova plugin):

```
    var cameraOptions = {
    quality: 75,
    destinationType: 0,
    targetWidth: 750,
    targetHeight: 500,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
    cameraDirection: 1,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: 0    // 0=JPG 1=PNG
};
```

PS: This solution might not be the best. Still hope to find a better one. But I will go on with this for now.